# JavaScript async/await polling to get a status - function doesn't return the correct data

Tags: javascript, django, async-await, fetch, celery

Context: asynchronous tasks management in Django with Celery and Redis.

I have a function that sends a POST request in Ajax. The server returns a task id.

With the task id I launch another function just after the POST request to fetch the task status in order to check if the worker has executed the task successfully.

Problem: I succeed in doing the polling with javascript and log the results. But at the end my function doesn't returns the correct data (the one in the if statement). It's as if the object returned by the if statement is ignored.

It's the first time I write such a function. Any help would be much appreciated

Code

```
function cancelSimcard() {
  const cancellationLink = document.getElementById("cancellationLink");

  return {
    notificationOpen: false,
    message: "à remplacer",

    async sendCancellationRequest() {
      const data = await fetch(cancellationLink.dataset.url, {
        method: "POST",
      });
      const result = await data.json();
      const status = await getStatus(result.task_id);
    },
  };

  async function getStatus(task_id) {
    const statusData = await fetch(`/parc/task_status/${task_id}`, {
      method: "GET",
    });
    const statusResult = await statusData.json();

    if (statusResult.task_status === "SUCCESS") {
      console.log("DATA FROM SUCCESS BLOCK", statusResult);
      return statusResult;
    } else {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      await getStatus(statusResult.task_id);
    }
    console.log("DATA AT THE END", statusResult);
  }
}
```

Console result:

[image]

**I'm trying to get the data from the success block to pass it in sendCancellationRequest() function. **

Comment: You're ignoring the result of your recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getStatus` function doesn't return anything when executing the `else` block, so it returns `undefined`. In other words, whatever the recursive call of `getStatus` returns, it is ignored, and `undefined` is returned instead.

This kind of polling can be implemented with a loop instead of recursion, which lowers the likelihood of making such a mistake:

```
  // Define this once for all:
  const delay = ms => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

  async function getStatus(task_id) {
    while (true) { // Loop
      const statusData = await fetch(`/parc/task_status/${task_id}`, {
        method: "GET",
      });
      const statusResult = await statusData.json();
      if (statusResult.task_status === "SUCCESS") {
        console.log("DATA FROM SUCCESS BLOCK", statusResult);
        return statusResult;
      }
      await delay(1000);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your solution seems to be the cleanest.

Answer (score 1):

The recursive calls are being made, but the result is not being returned back to the original caller as mentioned in the comment, therefore, you need to be sure that the the result of the recursive call is returned properly:

```js
function cancelSimcard() {
  const cancellationLink = document.getElementById("cancellationLink");

  return {
    notificationOpen: false,
    message: "à remplacer",

    async sendCancellationRequest() {
      const data = await fetch(cancellationLink.dataset.url, {
        method: "POST",
      });
      const result = await data.json();
      const status = await getStatus(result.task_id);
      return status; // return the final status back
    },
  };

  async function getStatus(task_id) {
    const statusData = await fetch(`/parc/task_status/${task_id}`, {
      method: "GET",
    });
    const statusResult = await statusData.json();

    if (statusResult.task_status === "SUCCESS") {
      console.log("DATA FROM SUCCESS BLOCK", statusResult);
      return statusResult;
    } else {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
      let finalResultesult = await getStatus(statusResult.task_id); 
      return finalResultesult // return the result 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In one of my attempt I tried to return a value in the else block but without assigning a variable. I didn't know I must assign a variable to store the result of an await function. Your solution works! Maybe the answer provided by trincot is cleaner that is why I have accepted it. Thank you very much for your help 